# How to hide CPScatterPlot inside CPXYGraph

Tags: ios, core-plot

How can I hide a `CPScatterPlot` inside `CPXYGraph` ?
I have tried using following line of code, but its crashing. Any clue?

```
[[[graph allPlots] objectAtIndex:0] setHidden:TRUE];
```

**Note** :`[graph allPlots]` returns 4 objects of `CPScatterPlot`

Thanks

Pratik Goswami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, seems Issue is already updated at CorePlot site,

Solution - I changed CPTLayer class setHidden method code from

```
if ( newHidden != self.hidden ) {
    self.hidden = newHidden;
    if ( !newHidden ) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

with this one

```
if ( newHidden != self.hidden ) {
    [super setHidden:newHidden];
    if ( !newHidden ) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

thanks

Pratik